# How to compare and update array data in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, compare, updating

I have an array of fruits which has following elements

```
var fruits = ['Mango','Orange', 'Banana', 'Mango', 'Grapes', 'Orange', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Mango']
```

And I want generate an output of object array which can be

```
result = [{fruit : 'Mango', Count : 3}, {fruit : 'Orange', Count : 2}, {fruit : 'Banana', Count : 2},{fruit : 'Grapes', Count : 1}, {fruit : 'Apple', Count : 2}]
```

How can I achieve the same?

Answer (score 3):

use `reduce` to create an object with keys as fruit name. If the key already exist increment the count else create an object with properties `fruit` and `count`, initialized to zero.

```js
const fruits = ['Mango', 'Orange', 'Banana', 'Mango', 'Grapes', 'Orange', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Mango'];

const output = Object.values(fruits.reduce((a, fruit) => {
  if (!a[fruit]) {
    a[fruit] = {
      fruit,
      count: 0
    };
  }
  a[fruit].count += 1;
  return a;
}, {}));

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

First calculate individual fruits the count with the help of [**reduce()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and finally convert that individual count to your expected object by [**map()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
const fruits = ['Mango','Orange', 'Banana', 'Mango', 'Grapes', 'Orange', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Mango']

const count = Object.values(fruits.reduce((old, cur) => (old[cur] = old[cur] || {fruit: cur, count: 0}, old[cur].count++, old), {}))

console.log(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
const fruits = ['Mango', 'Orange', 'Banana', 'Mango', 'Grapes', 'Orange', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Mango'];

const rst = Object.values(fruits.reduce((acc, ele) => (acc[ele] = {fruit: ele, count: (((acc[ele]||[])['count'])+=1) ||0}, acc),[]));

console.log(rst)
```